# PowerShell: Parse CSV file and remove only the third comma

Tags: powershell, csv, txt

I would to remove only the fifth comma in a CSV file and remove all additional space.

i.e.
Original file
A,B100537     ,8438,TRUST                        ,VECCO 4 PORT USB 2.0 MINI HUB  ,BLACK                              ,0000000000000009.01,14591

result
A,B100537 ,8438,TRUST COMPUTER ,VECCO 4 PORT USB 2.0 MINI HUB BLACK ,0000000000000009.01,14591

Code:

```html
$x = Get-Content file.txt 

$x | Foreach-Object {$_.Trim() -replace '^([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*),(.*)$', '$1 $2' -replace '\s+', ' ' }  |  Set-Content output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a regular expression.

```
Get-Content Filename.csv | 
  Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace '^([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*),(.*)$', '$1 $2' 
  } | Set-Content Output.csv
```